What binary format is the binary mesh export and how can it be converted to ASCII with Python?
I have generated some large meshes using Gmsh via the Python API. The ASCII files can be Gigabytes. Since binary files are smaller and faster to read, I set Gmsh to save the mesh files in binary format. My current issue is trying to figure out how to read that binary mesh back into Python in an interpretable format.
Further, I need the code to be compatible with the current code base I am using, which expects the ASCII data that I get when saving the mesh in ASCII format. I believe that if I can get read in the binary file and convert it to ASCII in memory, I can trick the other library I am using into using that. Hopefully, this will still be faster than reading in ASCII data (though I do not yet know if that will be true).
So, my questions are:

What binary encoding does Gmsh use for the save files?
How can the binary mesh file be read back into Python and converted to ASCII?

Here is a simplified version of the Gmsh tutorial 1 code (ref) modified to save the mesh in either ASCII or binary format.
import gmsh
import sys

binary = True
if binary:
    argv = ["","-bin"]
else:
    argv = []
gmsh.initialize(argv=argv)

gmsh.model.add("t1")

lc = 1e-2
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(0, 0, 0, lc, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(.1, 0, 0, lc, 2)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(.1, .3, 0, lc, 3)
p4 = gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(0, .3, 0, lc)

gmsh.model.geo.addLine(1, 2, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(3, 2, 2)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(3, p4, 3)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(4, 1, p4)

gmsh.model.geo.addCurveLoop([4, 1, -2, 3], 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addPlaneSurface([1], 1)

gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()

gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(1, [1, 2, 4], 5)
gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [1], name="My surface")

gmsh.model.mesh.generate(2)
if binary:
    gmsh.write("t1_binary.msh")
else:
    gmsh.write("t1_ascii.msh")
gmsh.finalize()

My initial naive approach was to read the file in binary format and try .decode(), but this approach fails once it gets past the $Entities line.
mesh_file = []
with open("t1_binary.msh", "rb") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
        mesh_file.append(line.decode())

When it fails I get the error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 72: invalid start byte.
I'm on Linux and tried running file t1_binary.msh to see if that would give me any useful information, but all I got was t1_binary.msh: data (i.e. it didn't provide any information about the binary format).

Addressing comments:

Have you tried looking at the source code of gmsh.write()?

Yes, I have tried looking into that code. gmsh.py's write function (link) calls lib.gmshWrite (I think that's this: link), which is C++. That C++ function calls gmsh::write (I think that's this: link) which seems to call gmshWrite, going in a full circle. I'm not sure if I'm looking at the wrong function definitions.

What kind of ASCII output do you expect? This is binary data, not text, right?

I expect to be able to recover the ASCII data saved into t1_ascii.msh when I set binary to False.

Have you tried looking at the source code of gmsh.write()?

@Barmar Yes, I have. See my edited answer for why it didn't get me anywhere.

Does gmsh.open() not do the job?

@jasonharper It will read it in, but then I don't know what to do from there. I'm not sure how I could get the ASCII result from that (without writing to ASCII and then reading that in).

What kind of ASCII output do you expect? This is binary data, not text, right?

@Barmar Without passing argv=["","-bin"] to gmsh.initialize, the output of gmsh.write is ASCII. I believe the binary version is the binary encoding of the same output data. As I mentioned, I want to save the files as binary for space and speed of reading, but I need to decode them. (Hopefully, the decoding process with the data already in memory will be faster than reading in an ASCII file.)

You could just use Gmsh GUI or Gmsh command line access to read binary msh file and then to write it a desired format. It have to work without writing some code.

While the GUI might be able to read in the mesh, I need to do it through python code.

I see two alternative ways. Firstly, gmsh.read() and to have full access to solution. Secondly, to learn python binary i/o for direct msh-file read.

What gmsh.read() function are you referring to? I can't find it in the Python API. And I'd like to be able to use Python binary I/O if I can't find another way, but that requires understanding what binary encoding is used.

Binary msh format description is in the Gmsh reference manual (gmsh.pdf). It is similar to the ascii format.  The gmsh.read() is in Gmsh API.
